# How to get Textbox control in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a HTML textbox

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" size="10" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

Now i need to set the value of textbox to "abcd";

I tried `datepicker.Text = "abcd";` Error is `"the name datepicker does not exist in current context"...`

I tried finding the Control and assigning the value but still could not do it.

Is there any other way to do it??
Thanks

Comment: You need to learn the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.

Answer (score 5):

You'll first need to make your `<input>` control a server side tag, using the `runat="Server"` attribute:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" size="10" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

Then, you can modify the value using C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   datepicker.Text = "New Value"; // Initial value for input field
}
```

If you want to modify the value on the *client* side, using jQuery, I'd first suggest making the ID static:

```
<input runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" type="text" size="10" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

Then you can do:

```
$("#datepicker").val('New Value');
```

Anywhere after the page has been loaded.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Comment: if you didnt want to use the ClientIDMode="Static" option you could use the <%=datepicker.ClientID %> in js

Comment: the value "abcd" is coming from database. Then how can i set value to "datepicker" in .aspx.cs file??

datepicker.Text is not working and if i add runat="server" then jquery doesnt work